# TibcoBW how to get inbound and outbound SOAP message during exception

Tags: logging, soap, tibco

We're trying to get inbound and outbound SOAP message by following this link

https://www.tibcommunity.com/docs/DOC-2642

```
java.property.com.tibco.plugin.soap.trace.inbound=true
java.property.com.tibco.plugin.soap.trace.outbound=true
java.property.com.tibco.plugin.soap.trace.filename=c:/temp/soap.txt
java.property.com.tibco.plugin.soap.trace.pretty=true
```

But it only going to log SOAP message for NO EXCEPTION, if we have exception no message is logged in soap.txt.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting the `bw.plugin.http.server.debug` engine property to true